# ExtJS ViewPort ContentEl not rendering Google Visualisation API Pie Chart

Tags: extjs

I am unable to render google pie chart in my border layout of the interface. Though the pie chart works fine on separate html page.

The div is as follows:

The javascript code looks like this:
{
title: 'View Interactive Reports',
ContentEl: "pChartMap",
plain: true,
bodyStyle: 'padding:5px',
border: false,
autoScroll: true
}

I am not sure about the **ContentEl** thing. It works fine, if there is simple text there but since the google chart is based on google visualisation api and an AJAX call where there is a function call as:
google.setOnLoadCallback(createChart);

Any ideas how to render this will be appreciated.

Cheers
Ali

Answer (score 0):

Have you check this? http://www.sencha.com/blog/2008/10/13/google-visualization/

Sadly the [example page](http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/google-visualization/gvisualization.html) is broken, but is just because the sencha site has not the *2.2 source of ExtJS* anymore; or at least not there where the sample expect it; but if you download the page and use [ExtJS 2.3.0](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/download.php) it will work.

Anyway, you only need to download this js: http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/google-visualization/GVisualizationPanel.js

And then just use the `Ext.ux.GVisualizationPanel`. Here is an example I tested:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var lineChartDs = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: [
            {name: 'yr', type: 'string'}
            ,{name: 'sales', type: 'int'}
            ,{name: 'expenses', type: 'int'}
        ],
        data: [['2004',1000,400],['2005',1170,460],['2006',860,580],['2007',1030,540]]
    });
    var lineChart = new Ext.ux.GVisualizationPanel({
        id: 'lineChart',
        visualizationPkg: 'linechart',
        title: 'Company Performance Sample',
        store: lineChartDs,
        columns: [
            {dataIndex: 'yr', label: 'Year'}
            ,{dataIndex: 'sales', label: 'Sales'}
            ,{dataIndex: 'expenses', label: 'Expenses'}
        ]
    })
    new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [lineChart]
    });
});
```